# Why do user agents / browsers lie

Tags: browser, browser-detection, browser-feature-detection

I have read several articles on feature detection and that it is more reliable than browser detection because browsers lie.

I couldn't find any information on why they lie. Does anyone know the reason why they would do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, Webmasters do browser sniffing to find the capabilities of a browser and limit what they send to the browser. If a browser lies about it's capabilities they will receive more from the webmaster, you can read more:

http://farukat.es/journal/2011/02/499-lest-we-forget-or-how-i-learned-whats-so-bad-about-browser-sniffing

http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/

Comment: browsers do not lie about their features. But you can change the user agent string via any developer tool. Or...there are so many variations of user agent strings it is impossible to keep a valid data base of browsers/device combinations with their appropriate capabilities. What if the OS gets upgraded and now suddenly feature X works? So many scenarios. This is why feature detection is the right way to go. They cannot lie about that, only implement features incorrectly.

Comment: Could you provide some sources to your information? My first source comes from Faruk Ates, the creator of Modernizr (feature detection) who says "The biggest problem with UA sniffing is the “UA” part, because browsers lie. A lot. They started lying with the release of Microsoft Internet Explorer 2.0, and they continue to lie to this very day. Browsers lie about who they are and what they can do all the time." and without further proof from you I am more inclined to believe him.

Comment: When the Edge browser user agent string contains the things like "Mozilla", "Safari", "Chrome", and "Gecko" those are lies. All browsers do this.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple:

Because web sites look at the user agent string and make assumptions about the browser, which are then invalid when the browser is updated to a new version.

This has been going on almost since the begining of the web. Browser vendors don't want their new versions to break the web, so they tweak the UA string to fool the code on existing sites.

Ultimately, if everyone used the UA string responsibly and updated their sites whenever new browser versions come out, then browsers wouldn't need to lie. But you have to admit, that's asking quite a lot.

Feature detection works better because when a new browser version comes out with that feature, the detection will pick it up automatically without the either browser needing to do anything special nor the site owner.

Of course, there are times when feature detection doesn't work perfectly -- eg maybe if a feature exists but has bugs in a particular browser. In that case, yes, you may want to do browser detection as a fall-back. But in most cases, feature detection is a much better option.

Answer (score 0):

Another more modern reason is to just avoid demands to install mobile apps (where product owners contol what I can and can't do with content. No thanks!).

Today Reddit started to block viewing subreddits in case they detect a mobile browser in UserAgent so I had to change it just to be able to view content.